# How to distribute app ios using appcelerator?

Tags: ios, appcelerator

Hy. I try distribute my app in applestore using appcelerator cli.

I run this command: 
appc run -p ios -T dist-applestore.

But my console returns: 
[image]

Comment: did you try to clean your build folder `ti clean`. Also please add your Xcode and appc sdk/cli versions (`appc info`). The same error appears for different app frameworks, so might not be related to appc but to the setup. You can also try to delete your prov. profiles and download them again. And compile with `-l trace` to see more log output

Comment: Hi, thanks for help.
I solved this problem creating new certificates.